# R return only one row for each value in vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with rows of repeating values for example:

```
id
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
D
D
```

What I would like to achieve is a line of code that retains only one value for each value in another vector, for example in:

```
keeps <- c("A", "C")
```

The result should be this:

```
id
A
C
```

Comment: Which of the three rows of A and two rows of C do you want to keep? The first, last, random?

Comment: first would be fine, but extra points for all possible ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df$id %in% c("A", "C") & !duplicated(df$id),,drop = FALSE]
#   id
# 1  A
# 6  C
```

or this:

```
unique(df[df$id %in% c("A", "C"),,drop = FALSE])
#   id
# 1  A
# 6  C
```

Comment: The first one did it! So I subsetted on df$id in keeps AND I did not duplicate the row if the df$id was duplicated... but what does drop = FALSE do?

Comment: With a one-column data frame (or matrix), `drop=FALSE` will make the result remain a data frame, whereas leaving it out will collapse the result to a vector.  Try both and check the difference